Identify a '80s sci-fi/horror movie
I'm trying to identify an old movie from a single scene. At that time I was a child, the movie seemed to be kind of a sci-fi/horror genre, my parents didn't let me see the whole movie, I just clearly remember that single scene.
I can suppose it was a sci-fi movie, and it could be from the '80s, for sure older than 1994. It is probably set on a spaceship. We see a woman immobilized on something like a surgical table, then a little circular saw moved by a robotic arm that is going (I suppose) to slice the woman's body for some experiment or maybe just in order to kill her (for example onboard computer getting mad), the woman reasonably starts screaming and then we see some blood splashing over the table. Nothing else.
We don't see (at least in that scene) any alien creatures, just the woman and the saw and the blood.

most definitely "Alien"

I don't remember that in Alien.

@MeatTrademark I believe there's a similar scene in Prometheus, so must have mixed the two movies up. Been a while since I saw 'em ^^

Definitely in Prometheus. It happens.

Didn't Fire in the Sky (1993) have some intense abduction operation sequence(s)? Could that be it?

"Fire in the Sky" seems the most similar, but I remember a woman not a man (as in this movie, right?).

I have seen a movie that had a scene like this, but it was quite old; don't remember if it was a man or woman on the table, but the bad guy was showing that the person could get cut and some laser robot arm would fix it right away and he was using that to put pressure on someone else

This is newer than 1994, but could it be Alien Abduction, (2005)?  From Wikipedia,

They wake up in a cell on the ship. Jean uses the camera's night
  vision to explore the alien glyphs and passages. They eventually
  rounded up and pushed into a room where they are tied down and
  vivisected.


The scene I remember could represent an alien abduction, but I've seen that movie about 20 years ago, it can't be most recent

Perhaps you saw the film Demon Seed? 
I think this might be the film you saw because there is a scene where a woman is on a table immobilized while a robot attacks her with robot appendages.
From IMDb

A scientist creates Proteus--an organic super computer with artificial
  intelligence which becomes obsessed with human beings, and in
  particular the creators wife.


Please elaborate on why you think this is the correct answer.

Can that be Lexx ? ... There are multiple scenes with cutting people apart.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178149/




I am not sure if there is a woman on surgical table in this movie, but maybe it was Hardware from 1990? There is a saw scene in this trailer (1:19)



